# Как выводить десятичное число в шестнадцатиричке?

Tags: java

У нас есть число 10
Выводя его через `String.format("%#x",10)` мы получим **0xa**, Как сделать так, чтобы вывод был **0x0A**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

может подойдет

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;

public class App {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    System.out.println(String.format("0x%02X", 10));

  }
}
```